# Junit Share External Resource Between Suite Classes

Tags: java, junit

How can I share an `ExternalResource` between two classes in a junit test suite?

**TestSuite.java**

```
@RunWith(Suite.class)
@SuiteClasses({ TestA.class, TestB.class })
public class TestSuite {
    @ClassRule
    public static MyResource res = new MyResource();
}
```

`MyResource` is an `ExternalResource` and I want to access `res` in the test suite classes TestA and TestB.

**TestA.java**

```
public class TestA {
    @Test
    public void testA() {
        System.out.println("####### testA");
        // res.someGetMethod();
    }
}
```

**TestB.java**

```
public class TestB {
    @Test
    public void testB() {
        System.out.println("####### testB");
        // res.someGetMethod();
    }
}
```

Thanks for looking.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `ClassRules` of the Suite are shared and accessible from its `TestCases`, it will intialised before the test case, and hence you can access it as you do with any public static variable

```
@Test
public void testA() {
    System.out.println("####### testA");
    TestSuite.res.someGetMethod();
}
```

Comment: Thanks, that is just what I was looking for!